# Mini Page Layout Hovers in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, security-review, mini-page-layout

Has anyone using [the mini page layout popup technique listed here](http://salesforceworld.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/displaying-pop-up-summaries-on-hover-in.html) in a managed package had the package rejected in security review because of it?

This is obviously an unsupported technique, but given that the display loaded should be adhering to security rules I don't know whether it would be accepted or not.

Please **do not** post any best guess answers as this is not a discussion board, but please do post if you've had a package using method accepted or rejected.

Comment: Have you considered asking them directly via their [office hours program](http://security.force.com/security/contact/ohours)?

Comment: Curious if, given that LEX is now around, you're still having troubles... 5 years later.

Comment: @DavidSchach I can't even remember what I was working on when I hit this now!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be 8+ years old and may possibly not be relevant anymore. Also, the OP seems to have commented indicating that he is unsure about actual intent for which posted this question.

Comment: @arut Yeah that's fair - I'll close it :)

Comment: Outdated thanks to the onward march of technology

Comment: @MattLacey Thanks for the proactive action, instead of leaving it to close votes. Much appreciated.

Comment: @arut All good, just because I'm a mod I'm not biased towards 'protecting' my own content :)